# data Not Storing

Tags: php, mysql

this is my connection class

```
class Connection {

    public function query($sql){
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Connection error ". mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('liontours') or die("Database error ". mysql_error());
        $results = mysql_query($sql);
        $last_inserted_id = mysql_insert_id();      
        return array('results'=>$results, 'last_id'=>$last_inserted_id);
        }


    }
```

this is my model

```
    public function V_reg($v_no, $dl_no, $owner, $o_name, $o_nic, $i_date, $ex_date, $p_report, $nic, $s_name, $f_name, $initials, $dob, $stat, $v_type) {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `vehicledetails`(`vehicle_no`, `owner`, `owner_name`, `owner_nic`, `insured_date`, `ex_date`, `police_report`,`type`)
                VALUES ('$v_no','$owner','$o_name','$o_nic','$i_date','$ex_date','$p_report','$v_type')";

        $conn = new Connection();
        //vehicle id of last inserted record
        $vehicle_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $results = $conn->query($sql);
        $last_vehicle_record_id = $results['last_id'];
        $fk_key = $last_vehicle_record_id;
        //checking the first table insert successful if so do the second insert else must define counter measure in else part 
        if ($fk_key !== 0) {
                $sql1 = "INSERT INTO driverdetails (id, vehicle_id, nic,sir_name,first_name,dlNo,initials,dob,status )
                VALUES ('null', '$fk_key', '$nic','$s_name','$f_name','$dl_no', '$initials','$dob','$stat')";
                $results = $conn->query($sql1);

        }else{
            die('transaction failed').mysql_error();
        }

        return $results;
    }

}
```

i don't know what is wrong with this coding but it's not passing the data all the time it says transaction failed and no error given. just the text can some body tell me any thing wrong with this coding ? if there is no coding errors is it a problem with my database ?

Comment: remove id and its values 'null', no need for that

Comment: You're simply asssuming queries could not possibly ever fail. Major mistake. Never EVER assume success. Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @binku What MVC framework are you using. Depending on framework there may be a debugging level to set that will show the error.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or pdo: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php